# Quite a tricky SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table `EMPLOYEE` with 3 fields:

```
EMPLOYEE(ROLE SMALLINT, RATING INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR)
```

I need get from this table only 3 row. It's One row of each type with the highest rating in its type. The role of the field - is the discriminant that defines the specific role from list of the three values: DEVELOPER(1), TESTER(2), MANAGER (3). So the value of ROLE field can be either 1 or 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres specific short query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (role) role, name, rating
FROM employee
ORDER BY role, rating DESC
```

If 2 employee have same role and rating - one of them will be picked at random.

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic aggregation query (I'm assuming you are new to SQL):

```
select role, max(rating)
from employee
group by role
```

In response to the comment (I can see how the question is ambiguous).  The right way to do this in Postgres is using a window function:

```
select role, rating, name
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by role order by rating desc) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1
```

This version returns only one row, even if there are duplicates.  If you want all rows when there are multiples with the same max, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Where's NAME fild? Statement `GROUP BY role` doesn't work properly with  NAME in SELECT

Comment: I think the the row_number() would need to partition by role

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want, for each role, the name with the highest rating:

```
select role, rating, name
from employee as e1
where rating = (
  select max(rating) from employee
  where role = e1.role
)
```

This won't work right if you have two employees with the same role and rating, though. In that case, you'll need to select name in a subquery.